# How to Supress PMD duplicate in Objective-c ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pmd

While using **[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/snapshot/)** code analyser,
I have shown several duplicates which includes framework classes and delegates and datasource methods too, I just want to suppress those findings. I tried with [Suppress warnings](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/snapshot/usage/suppressing.html) not works. Also I can't find syntax for Objective-c. Can any one give me how to suppress duplicate findings in PMD?

1. I tried the below command for excluding the directory,

> ./run.sh cpd --files
> /Users/Arun/Documents/Projects/Sample
> --language objectivec --minimum-tokens 100 --format xml --exclude /Users/Arun/Documents/Projects/Sample/ExternalFrameworks.

2. I don't see any duplicate suppression syntax for objective-c.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support to have CPD ignore chunks of code in any other language than Java. The only option available is to fully ignore files using the `--exclude` flag.

Supporting it through comments (`// CPD-[OFF|ON]` | `/* CPD-[OFF|ON] */`) should be relatively easy since Objective-C is implemented using JavaCC.

The source code is tokenized [here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-objectivec/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/ObjectiveCTokenizer.java#L36-L39). CPD suppression consists merely of dropping the ignored tokens from `tokenEntries`.

To do so, you first need to find comments, this is done by checking if `currentToken.specialToken` is not null.

```
Token st = currentToken.specialToken;
while (st != null) {
  if (st.image.contains("CPD-OFF") {
    suppressing = true;
    break;
  }
  if (st.image.contains("CPD-ON") {
    suppressing = false;
    break;
  }
  st = st.specialToken;
}
```

and then checking if the value of `suppressing` before adding (or not) the token [here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-objectivec/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/ObjectiveCTokenizer.java#L37)

Final code should look something such as:

```
boolean suppressing = false;
while (currentToken.image.length() > 0) {
    if (!suppressing) {
        tokenEntries.add(new TokenEntry(currentToken.image, sourceCode.getFileName(), currentToken.beginLine));
    }
    currentToken = (Token) tokenManager.getNextToken();
    Token st = currentToken.specialToken;
    while (st != null) {
        if (st.image.contains("CPD-OFF") {
            suppressing = true;
            break;
        }
        if (st.image.contains("CPD-ON") {
            suppressing = false;
            break;
        }
        st = st.specialToken;
    }
}
```

PRs are always welcomed. This along with a couple unit tests should be enough to get this merged for the next release.

Comment: Support for this on Java has now been officially added. Doing so on other languages should be straight forward. https://github.com/pmd/pmd/pull/250